# What is the best practice in multifile error handling?

Tags: python, python-3.x, refactoring, solid-principles

I have written pretty big project in python and started my first refactoring using SOLID principles. Could you advice me some good practice in multifile error handling? I dont know where to put my try catch block to keep my code clean and readable. My code needs to work 24/7 in scheduler loop so there cannot be unhandled exception and there is a lot of validators. Oversimplified code to picture:

```
import schedule
import time

def f1_step1():
    #do something
    pass

def f1_step2():
    #do something
    pass

def data_validation(data):
    #return result
    pass
    

def f1():
    data=f1_step1()
    if(!data_validation(data))
        break
    f1_step2()
    
schedule.every(10).minutes.do(f1)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: First tip, you should make a error logger, function, in one of your file. Helps quite a lot in big projects

Comment: Yeah i know i have error logger in my project, but this code is just for smarter than me to point me where try catch block should take place ideally. Function needs to stop working when error occured and not continue next steps

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read your question properly. Just place try  and except in the while loop. What's wrong with that?

Comment: Nothing is wrong with that actually. It can be written in a few ways. I am just asking for the best practice. Now i have try catch in function f1 and it looks quite messy